# SyncFusion GridDataBoundGrid DataBinding Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion's GridDataBoundGrid control and binding my custom List.
One of the properties is  Nullable DateTime (DateTime?). When I add a new row to the grid and started editing in the DateTime column, If I type Alphanumeric, A message box displays some thing like "XX is not a valid value for Nullable '1".
1. How do I handle this to put some more meaningful maessage?

I would appreciate the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Use `DirectSaveCellInfo` property to save once you complete editing a cell.

```
this.gridDataBoundGrid1.Binder.DirectSaveCellInfo = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

The CurrentCellErrorMessage event will be triggered before showing the error message. You can handle this event and show your custom MessageBox and cancel the event. Also you can set your custom text to the Text property. The following code shows the implementation of the same.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.gridDataBoundGrid.CurrentCellErrorMessage += new GridCurrentCellErrorMessageEventHandler(gridDataBoundGrid_CurrentCellErrorMessage);
}

void gridDataBoundGrid_CurrentCellErrorMessage(object sender, GridCurrentCellErrorMessageEventArgs e)
{
//e.Text = "My Text";
MessageBox.Show("Type your custom message here. The original text is: \"" + e.Text+ "\"");
e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Arulraj,I have another issue. In My GridDataBoundGrid, I have the user rows added and edited dynamically. Onc ethey add a row and enetr information in the cells and click a save button on the form, the data is not getting updated in the underying data source. They have to select another row in order to make those changes updated in the datasource. Is there any way I can force update the datasource after the cell is edited>